# Can´t bake larger textures than 1000x1000px

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I have a problem with baking textures in cycles. No matter what image size I create for UV coordinates, the baked image allways shrinks to 1000x1000 px, thus gets pixelated.
Do you have any ideas, why is it happening and how could I solve it?

Comment: How are you creating the image, and are you sure it is baking to the same image you want?

Comment: UV Coordinates do not determine the pixel by pixel dimension size of the image.  Your specification of dimension at image creation time does this.

Comment: I have this high-poly model. after unwrapping it with Smart UV Project I created New Image and set it to be 2000x2000 (example)--
http://postimg.org/image/4miw72uwj/

before baking, the image had this size in UV/Image Editor--
http://postimg.org/image/mdq0dcl2r/

immediately after baking it shrunk (it was not me scrolling away)--
http://postimg.org/image/w8acrr1l3/

when I opened the image in Photoshop, it shows its real dimensions and quality. now it´s 1024x1012px and really pixelated--
http://postimg.org/image/5nhzk8l3t/

thank you for you answers :)

Comment: Did you remember to select your image in the node-editor while baking?

Answer (score 2):

Did you set the image texture in your material node setup to the new larger image file?

[image]

I did bake a cube to a 3k by 3k texture without problem.

Comment: oh thank you sooo much! I didn´t get the thing about linking new image texture to the newly created image. you´re the best, best wishes

Wrawraww

Comment: It kind of got answered in the comments by  DrRiisTab. I just tried to create a nice answer out of it :)

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider marking it as correct or at least up voting